# jQuery conflict when adding a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i'm using wordpress 3.9 and want to use [this plugin](https://github.com/markgoodyear/headhesive.js/) in my theme . but when i want to add this :

```
var headhesive = new Headhesive('.header');
```

all scripts stop working in my theme .
how should i use this that works in my theme ?
i think that it's jQuery conflict

Comment: Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome and tell us if you have anything there, like an error or warning.

Comment: There is too little context here to assume what might be wrong. It might help if one would see the page where this problem occurs.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: _mergeObj is not defined &&& Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Maybe youve forgot to add something. This feed might help: https://github.com/markgoodyear/headhesive.js/issues/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the `$`s conflict. If that's the case you can use `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>` in your header.php file and add `$.noConflict();` before you run any jquery code.

see: http://wpapi.com/wordpress-and-jquery-conflicts-how-to-solve-that/
for more info.